# RSS not displaying in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, xslt, web, rss

I'm trying to work with an rss feed I've created.  It has two linked css and xls documents, one css as a fail safe in case xsl doesn't work and another css for when xls formats the feed.
The url is here:

http://rockthepatch.com/rss/current-events.xml

The rss feed looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://www.rockthepatch.com/css/rss.css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.rockthepatch.com/rss/current-events.xsl"?>

<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <title>Upcoming Rock the Patch! Events</title>
    <link>http://www.rockthepatch.com/rss/current-events.xml</link>
    <description>See what's coming up below:</description>
    <atom:link href="http://www.rockThePatch.com/rss/current-events.xml" rel="self"     type="application/rss+xml" />

    <item>
      <title>Thursday's Open Mic at Ole Simms</title>
      <link>https://www.facebook.com/olesimrells</link>
      <description>Join Patches at open mic night at Terre Haute's Ole Simmerls Bar around 9 P.M. every Thursday.</description>
      <guid>http://www.indstate.edu/mpa/sarah/rockThePatch/rss/item0001</guid>
      <pubDate>Mon, 10 Oct 2011 09:15:00 EST</pubDate>
      <author>sklinefelter89@gmail.com (Patches)</author>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Fall Break is Here!</title>
      <link>http://www.indstate.edu/academicaffairs/calendar.htm</link>
      <description>School and work will not happen on Friday due to FALL BREAK!!!    </description>
      <guid>http://www.indstate.edu/mpa/sarah/rockThePatch/rss/item0002</guid>
      <pubDate>Fri, 07 Oct 2011 02:23:00 EST</pubDate>
      <author>sklinefelter89@gmail.com (Patches)</author>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

The xsl looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rockthepatch.com/css/xsl.css"     type="text/css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>Upcoming Rock the Patch! Events</h2>
        <table border="1px">
          <tr>
            <th>Name of Event</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Posted</th>
            <th>Author</th>
         </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
        <tr>
              <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          </td>
          <!-- <td>
            <a href="&lt;xsl:value-of select='link'/&gt;" title="Link">
              <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
            </a>
          </td> -->
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
          </td>
          <td>
                <a href="mailto:sklinefelter89@gmail.com" title="sklinefelter89@gmail.com">
                  <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't want the file to download, but everytime I click on the link, it downloads opposed to displaying in any of the browsers...can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the HTTP Headers from your URL. You are sending a content-type of `application/xhtml+xml`. You should change this to `application/rss+xml`. That *should* do the trick.

I put your xml file on a coldfusion server to replcate the issue. Then changed the extenstion to cfm, added `<cfcontent type = "application/rss+xml">`, and it worked as you desire (no download).

Comment: I'm actually think it may be an issue with godaddy hosting the more I research but I'm still unsure.  I added type="application/rss+xml" to the rss header but still not having any luck.

Comment: I'm also getting this: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/rss+xml: "http://rockthepatch.com/rss/current-events.xml".

Comment: I've played around with fiddler intercepting your server responses. Nothing seems to help very much. There is a lot of literature on the web that shows how poor Chrome implemented RSS feed consumption. There is no built-in way to subscribe to a feed. Google's recommendation is to install the RSS Subscription Extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd